# How to unpush a command that does not really run in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, undo-redo

I am using Qt's undo/redo framework. I push an undo command to an undo stack. However, the functions called in the redo of the command sometimes does nothing since some requirements are not met. In this case, how to let the undo stack go back to the the sate before the command is pushed?

I just read the source code of the `QUndoStack::push()`. It calls redo at the first beginning. If so, I think I only need to throw an exception in the `redo()` function if nothing really done. Should this work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. When you push an undo command to the stack you're doing so because you're making an actual change to your document or data model. As soon as a command is pushed the stack will call its `redo()` method. So you should really check if the requirements are met before you push the command to the stack. Don't push any commands that won't actually make any changes.

Comment: I just read the source code of the QUndoStack::push(). It calls redo at the first beginning. If so, I think I only need to throw an exception in the redo() function if nothing really done. Should this work?

Comment: Does it add the command to the stack before it calls redo? If it does then the command would still be on the stack so a user could still `undo` it. And even if it doesn't put it on the stack before calling `redo()` it's a really bad idea to rely on an undocumented implementation detail as they could change the QUndoStack implementation in a future update that would break your app's reliance on the current behavior. What's wrong with just doing a check before you add it to the stack?

Comment: For performance. The check is quite time-consuming. I can split the function to two functions. One is to check, the other is to do the task directly. But the split is dangerous since the user may use the second one without checking first.